# Proper syntax in a for loop

Tags: python, python-3.x, for-loop, syntax

I'm trying to make a convertor of temperature units, and I ran into a problem trying to make it stupid-proof.

```
Units = "Celsius", "celsius", "Fahrenheit", "fahrenheit", "Kelvin", "kelvin"
temp_o = input("¿Do you wish to convert Celsius, Fahrenheit, or Kelvin?")
for temp_o not in Units:
    temp_o = input("Insert an accepted unit of measurement")
```

This section of the code is giving me the following error:

```
 File "C:\XXX\XXX\XXX\XXX.py", line 7
    for temp_o not in Units:
                           ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

It's saying that the ":" is invalid syntax (?). If I remove it, it doesn't work either. Any idea?

Comment: What does `for ... not in ...:` mean to you? Did you mean `if ... not in ...:`?

Comment: @mkrieger1 I think the `for` should have been a `while`.

Answer (score 2):

The error with the code is the use of the for loop in this specific situation instaed of the while loop. The for loop is used to perform the same action on each element, but you want to check if the value of temp_o is not present in the Units list, and if so, you want to have the user to input a valid unit of measurement, until he got it right.

```
Units = ["celsius", "fahrenheit", "kelvin"]
temp_o = input("""Do you wish to convert Celsius, Fahrenheit, or Kelvin?
--> """).lower()
while temp_o not in Units:
    temp_o = input("Insert an accepted unit of measurement: ").lower()
```

1. Add parentheses to the Units variable to make it a list.
2. Instead of writing multiple versions of the same temperature as Celsius or celsius, you can simply change all temperatures to lowercase and use the "lower" method with the temp_o variable.
3. Replace for with while.

This should make it work.